# Can Sefardim eat meat in the homes of Ashkenazim?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, slaughter-shochet-shecht, stringency-chumrah

In light of the details found in answers to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43974/chalak-or-glatt) question, which suggest that neither [Chassidish](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/general/77155/satmar-rebbe-speaks-out-against-ashkenazic-shechita-practice.html) nor glatt nor non-glatt Ashkenazi meat is halachically acceptable for Sefardim, would there be any leniency for a Sefardi to eat meat in the home of an Ashkenazi? Presumably, the Ashkenazi would not be serving Beit Yosef meat, since--according to details in the first link above--that meat would not be kosher for the Ashkenazi himself (at least if he held to the glatt standard, and possibly also if he did not).*

Are there any kashrus standards for meat that would certainly be acceptable to both Ashkenazim and Sefardim in the stricter (i.e., ~glatt-eating) groups?

(*I've encountered both opinions on whether both glatt and non-glatt Ashkenazim may eat beit yosef meat. CYLOR if it applies to you)

Comment: Are you asking for leniencies for a Sefardi to eat at an Ashkenazi's house, just if such a piece of meat is possible, or if some current Hashgacha markets it, or what they call it? I'm not sure exactly what you're getting at.

Comment: @DoubleAA How about this: If I wanted to serve a mixed group, what would I serve them? Assume the Ashkenazim don't eat non-glatt.

Comment: Note the answer you link to is discussing an animal in which a sircha (a lesion) is found on the lungs. If no sirchot are found, it's for sure kosher accd to anyone and everyone.

Comment: @SAH That is a question. Is it what you want to ask in this post?

Comment: @DoubleAA Good point about no lesions. Do you know of any standard that insists on that?

Comment: Do you mean a modern Kashrut company? A brand of food? Are you looking for a term that describes it (Bli Shum Sirkhah seems clear and understandable)? A group of people that hold of such a standard?

Comment: @DoubleAA Let's say an indication on the packaging. Is Bli Shum Sikhah one of those? Is it in current use anywhere? --I don't know that I'll change my question to say "indication on the packaging" because at some point, additional specificity stops helping the question in any real way. IMO at least.

Comment: @DoubleAA Would you like me to change my question to "Is there any type of meat that is kosher for both Sefardim and (glatt) Ashkenazim"? I'd be willing to do that

Comment: I would ask can sifardim, eat glat meat, or must it be glat Bais yosef

Comment: @SAH American glat Bais yosef can be eaten by Ashkenazim, but halak bait yosef might be a problem since they might use bait yosefs leniencyz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rav Ovadiah Yosef (Yabiah Omer 5; YD 3) relies on the heter of R' Shmuel Abohav (D'var Shmuel ch.320). He says that if you do not actually know if the piece of meat you are eating is "chalak" or not, (of course you know the hechsher is definitely not "chalak" but that doesn't matter here) then you can eat it at an Ashkenazi home; especially if it is a seudas mitzvah.

Ashkenazi meat processors do not remove the better meat and throw it out! They just allow for the lenient meat to be included in the food offered. Therefore, no one knows if this steak from the package is from an extra smooth lunged cow or from one where the Ashkenazi Rabbi allowed for certain innocent lung issues that a Sefardi would not accept.

So it becomes a doubt of a doubt. The halachic term for this is a s'fek s'feka; or double doubt.

1) Maybe this piece is from a Sefardi type accepted cow?

2) Maybe the halachah is actually lenient like the Ashkenazim say it is!

The only way to make this case a problem would be if the Ashkenazi host tells the Sefardi: "I slaughtered this cow myself and saw in the lung certain issues that the Beis Yosef forbids but we Ashkenazim eat all day."

However, if its just a random piece of Ashkenazi meat in a package, then it falls under the double doubt system.

Due to this double doubt, R' Ovadiah Yosef allows Sefardim to eat meat at the home of Ashkenazim.

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: So is it correct that Ashkenazim - or at least those who hold glatt - cannot eat a piece of meat labeled "chalak" or "Beit Yosef chalak"? What if it says both "chalak" and "glatt"?

Comment: This answer cites an important source, but skips on any actual discussion of the Metziut. In some places the "better meat" is indeed removed and sold separately, for instance. Plus pretending that all Ashkenazi meat is the same seems a bit naive.

Comment: An ashkenazi can always eat chalak beit Yosef. Chalak beit Yosef is more machmir than normal glatt. Glatt for ashkenazim allows two small, easily removed adhesions on the animal's lungs, whilst chalak beit Yosef requires the lungs to be completely smooth.

Comment: @MosheSteinberg That just depends on the semantics. In principle, the Beit Yosef does allow certain adhesion that the Rama doesn't. Also the Rama doesn't say anything about limiting the number of adhesion to 2. Don't confuse modern Kashrut agency lingo with actual Halakhic claims

Comment: @moshesteinberg What about the label that is just "chalak"?

Comment: @SAH You'd have to ask whoever wrote the label what they meant. It's just a marketing term.