# Can an Ashkenazi use Bet Yosef Shechita or vice versa?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, meat, slaughter-shochet-shecht

For the most part, I gather that an Ashkenazi should not follow Sephardi minhag or vice versa. (E.g. - nusach hatefilla, kitniyot on Pesach.)

I am Ashkenazi. I am somewhat "liberal" regarding my use of *shechita*, i.e., I will use meat that is certified by a reliable rav. I am unfamiliar with what makes "Bet Yosef" shechita, generally use by Sephardim different from Ashkenazi shechita. Would an Ashkenazi be allowed to use Bet Yosef Shechita or can a Sephardi use a reliable Ashkenazi shechita or are they restricted to Bet Yosef shechita?

Comment: Bet Yosef is the equivalent of glatt kosher - one level up from regular kosher - certainly works for an Ashkenazi. Sefardim are more *machmir* than Ashkenazim regarding adhesions therefore many will not use Ashkenazi schita. All this is valid for Israel - I don't know enough about the US these days to comment

Comment: Even more literal than that @mbloch. A sign saying bet yosef without a teuda from a rabbi is the equivalent of a store advertising glatt kosher without a hashgacha from a rabbi.

Comment: Short answer: An Ashkenazi _can_ rely on Bet Yosef _shechita_ but a Sephardi _cannot_ rely on Ashkenazi _shechita_.

Comment: From what I understand, there is a dispute over what part of the checking process is min haTorah and what is derabbanan. The Sefaradim are more stringent than the Ashkenazim over this. I would need to look into it.

Comment: @mbloch That's not really true. The Beit Yosef permits some adhesions and prohibits others, while the Rama permits some adhesions and prohibits others. One is not exclusively more strict or lenient. Usually what's labeled as Beit Yosef nowadays is meat that has no adhesions at all, so it's fine for both. But that's not literally true about the in principle Sefardi/Ashkenazi positions.

Comment: @ezra It's not the shechita, it's the bedika, and in some regards the beit yosef is more lenient than the rama.

Comment: @DoubleAA נכון חבר

Comment: Uh, I think this might be a dupe of one of my questions from years ago

Comment: Possibly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43974/chalak-or-glatt

Comment: @DoubleAA with all due respect, I heard R Avraham Yosef (the son of R Ovadia) speak multiple times on this topic (in Israel he led their Beit Yosef *hashgacha*) and he explained it the way I did. "They are more *machmir*) doesn't mean they accept no adhesions

Comment: @mbloch Rabbi or no rabbi, you can't disagree about what the Beit Yosef and Rama held. Perhaps later Sefardim are more Machmir than the Beit Yosef in some of these areas. (I don't understand your last sentence since everyone accepts animals with no adhesions.)

Comment: @mbloch See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/43991/759 though as I indicated there modern marketing terms and technical halakhic positions in this area are very different things which can confuse people who don't know how to put things in the right context. What you said "Sefardim are more machmir than Ashkenazim regarding adhesions" is factually technically not true, even if it is true that among modern meat Kashrut-standards, the Sefardim accept fewer.

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think the question was about the halachic position of the Beit Yosef or the Rama. I think it was about modern-day schita.

Comment: @mbloch Maybe, but you said "Bet Yosef is the equivalent of glatt kosher" and "Sefardim are more machmir than Ashkenazim regarding adhesions" which are both technically false.

Comment: @DoubleAA I believe I am correct in practice and in Israel: Ashkenazim who eat glatt will eat Bet Yosef schita. R A Yosef holds that Sfardim cannot eat regular kosher schita and need glatt or Bet Yosef or what is called here *halak*

Comment: @mbloch Your last comment here is true I think and it doesn't contain the false claims I pointed out in your first comment.